# How is chance for a critical hit determined in Final Fantasy IX?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

All I've been able to find is the following:

> Your chance of a Critical Hit with the Attack Command is based on Spirit:
>
> Rnd MOD [Spr / 4] > Rnd MOD 100, attack will critical

from [here.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197338-final-fantasy-ix/faqs/44329)

and the slightly differently worded

> If Rnd MOD [Spr / 4] > Rnd (0...99), Hit is critical.

from [here.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Critical_Hit#Final_Fantasy_IX)

What is the left side of the expression saying? I know MOD means the remainder after division, but the MOD would just go 0, 1, 2, 3 as you gain spirit, meaning only spirit values one less than those evenly divisible by 4 would be valuable for scoring crits, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the equation is supposed to read: `(0 ... 99) mod (Spirit / 4) > (0 ... 99)`

That is, a Spirit of 44 would yield `(0 .. 99) mod 11` which is effectively `(0 .. 10)` which then rolls against `(0 .. 99)`.  Thus you'd have a 9% chance of a critical hit.